# pandas applying multicolumnindex to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

The situation is that I have a few files with time_series data for various stocks with several fields. each file contains

```
time, open, high, low, close, volume
```

the goal is to get that all into one dataframe of the form

```
field      open                              high                            ...
security    hk_1      hk_2      hk_3 ...      hk_1      hk_2      hk_3 ...  ...
time
t_1      open_1_1  open_2_1  open_3_1 ...  high_1_1  high_2_1  high_3_1 ...  ...            
t_2      open_1_2  open_2_2  open_3_2 ...  high_1_2  high_2_2  high_3_2 ...  ...
...        ...        ...       ... ...       ...       ...       ... ...  ...
```

I created a multiindex

```
fields = ['time','open','high','low','close','volume','numEvents','value']
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([security_name'], fields], names=['security', 'field'])
```

and for a start, tried to apply that multiindex to the dataframe I get from reading the data from csv (by creating a new dataframe and adding the index)

```
for c in eqty_names_list:

    midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[c], fields], names=['security', 'field'])

    df_temp = pd.read_csv('{}{}.csv'.format(path, c))
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(df_temp, columns=midx, index=df_temp['time'])
    df_temp.df_name = c
    all_dfs.append(df_temp)
```

However, the new dataframe only contains nan

```
security    1_HK
field       time    open    high    low     close   volume
time                                
 NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN      NaN
```

Also, it still contains a column for time, although I tried to make that the index (so that I can later join all the other dataframes for other stocks by index to get the aggregated dataframe).

How can I apply the multiindex to the dataframe without losing my data and then later join the dataframes looking like this

```
security    1_HK
field       time    open    high    low     close   volume
time
```

to create something like (note hierarchy field and security are switched)

```
field       time                open    high        ...
security    1_HK    2_HK ...    1_HK    2_HK ...    ...
time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can first get all files to list `files`, then with list comprehension get all DataFrames and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them by columns `(axis=1)`. If add parameter `keys`, you get `Multiindex` in columns:

Files:

[a.csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84444599/web/a.csv), 
[b.csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84444599/web/b.csv), 
[c.csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84444599/web/c.csv)

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp) for fp in files]

eqty_names_list = ['hk1','hk2','hk3']
df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=eqty_names_list, axis=1)

print (df)
  hk1       hk2       hk3      
    a  b  c   a  b  c   a  b  c
0   0  1  2   0  9  6   0  7  1
1   1  5  8   1  6  4   1  3  2
```

Last need [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.swaplevel.html) and [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0,1)
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
    a           b           c        
  hk1 hk2 hk3 hk1 hk2 hk3 hk1 hk2 hk3
0   0   0   0   1   9   7   2   6   1
1   1   1   1   5   6   3   8   4   2
```

Comment: Thanks. that works beautifully. Note for anyone who is looking at this; the order of files should match the order in eqty_names_list if you read data in like this