# Read multiple csvs into multiple dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Is there a way to read multiple csv files into Pandas through a loop and define them as such?

```
for i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']:
    csv_(i) = pd.read_csv('C:/test_{}.csv'.format(i))
```

I see multiple questions about reading and appending multiple csvs into a single dataframe. Not the other way around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `dict comprehension` for `dict` of `DataFrames`:

```
dfs = {i: pd.read_csv('C:/test_{}.csv'.format(i)) for i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}

print (dfs['a'])
```

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Oh wonderful! Initially I dismissed the idea but after playing with it a little all I had to do was add each `dict/DataFrames` into a `list` to perform multiple merge.

Comment: Thank you, If need one big dataframe, maybe help [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38850014/2901002)

Comment: Much appreciated!