# Use for loop to read multiple csv to multiple dataframes in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple csv files, named "csv_i", where i varies from 1 to 54. I want to create a for loop to read each one of these csv files in a similarly named dataframe (e.g. df_i), as such:

```
it = np.arange(1,55)
for i in it:
    my_csv = ('csv_{}.csv'.format(i))
    df_i = pd.read_csv(my_csv)
```

Can you help me with the last line of the code please? I cannot use something like: `"df_{}.format(i) = pd.read_csv(my_csv)`, so I was wondering how I can achieve it.

Please note, that I saw somewhere that you can create a dictionary and each pair of key-values will be each one of the 54 df, but I'd prefer to have 54 separate dfs instead. Thanks

Comment: Check this post on SO, this answers different ways in which it can be done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: i think this post could help you  [Read multiple csvs into multiple dataframes in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934137/read-multiple-csvs-into-multiple-dataframes-in-pandas)