# Read in multiple csv into separate dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a long list of csv files that I want to read as dataframes and name them by their file name. For example, I want to read in the file status.csv and assign its dataframe the name `status`. Is there a way I can efficiently do this using Pandas?

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934137/read-multiple-csvs-into-multiple-dataframes-in-pandas), I still have to write the name of each csv in my loop. I want to avoid that.

Looking at [this](https://medium.com/@kadek/elegantly-reading-multiple-csvs-into-pandas-e1a76843b688), that allows me to read multiple csv into one dataframe instead of many.

Comment: You can get all csv under current directory using `os.listdir(".")`, combined with `os.path.basename` to parse file name.

Comment: Are you open to using `dask`?  You could read in all the separate dataframes and have them contained in one data structure, i.e., a dask dataframe, partitioned by their original file name.  Docs are [here](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can list all csv under a directory using `os.listdir(dirname)` and combine it with `os.path.basename` to parse the file name.

```
import os

# current directory csv files
csvs = [x for x in os.listdir('.') if x.endswith('.csv')]
# stats.csv -> stats
fns = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x))[0] for x in csvs]

d = {}
for i in range(len(fns)):
    d[fns[i]] = pd.read_csv(csvs[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

you could create a dictionary of `DataFrames`:

```
d = {}  # dictionary that will hold them 

for file_name in list_of_csvs:  # loop over files

   # read csv into a dataframe and add it to dict with file_name as it key
   d[file_name] = pd.read_csv(file_name)
```