# How to read multiple csv into separate dataframe objects without putting it in a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read multiple files into separate dataframe objects: i.e., read 'train.csv' into an object called train and the same for 'test.csv'.

The advice I've found so far (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934137/read-multiple-csvs-into-multiple-dataframes-in-pandas) tend to read the different files into a dictionary or list. From there, I suppose I could generate e.g., train = dict[0] but is there a way to do it directly?

For now, I ran the following but would get an error:

```
files = ['train.csv', 'test.csv']
names = [train, test]

for file, name in zip(files, names):
    name = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Output/Error message:
`NameError: name 'train' is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a name this way reliably, this would mean messing with `globals`/`locals`, which is bad practice.

For just two files, the most explicit is:

```
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test  = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

If you need the loop, use a dictionary:

```
files = ['train.csv', 'test.csv']
names = ['train', 'test']

dfs = {}
for file, name in zip(files, names):
    dfs[name] = pd.read_csv(file)
```

For reference, see [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables).

Or use the file name as key:

```
files = ['train.csv', 'test.csv']

dfs = {f: pd.read_csv(f) for f in files}

# or, without the extension
dfs = {f.removesuffix('.csv'): pd.read_csv(f) for f in files}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using exec?
You can create your program line as a string and pass it to exec.

```
files = ['train.csv', 'test.csv']

for f in files:
    print(f"{f.removesuffix('.csv')} = pd.read_csv('{f}')")
```

This code generate the string outputs:

```
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

Now these strings can be passed to exec func as:

```
for f in files:
    exec(f"{f.removesuffix('.csv')} = pd.read_csv('{f}')")
```